# Php: Form auto-fill using $_SESSION variables with multiple php files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I already searched for an hour to solve the following problem, but I couldnt find an answer for my specific problem. I have some ideas, which I propose after the introduction to the problem.

Problem:

I have an html form in a php file. You can enter a name (first,mi,last) a phone number and an account number to that form. If a phone number is added, then the onblur function  *(using javascript file request.js)* on the input field of *phone number* is used to auto fill the other 4 fields using a hash, which *keys* are the *phone numbers* and the *values* are a json-object, which holds all 4 other values.

If the entered customer data doesn't exist in the hash, then it should be added by clicking on the submit-button using an ajax-request again.

the following shows the file with the input form: *index.php*:

```
<?php
   session_start();
// set the hash to session
// add the new item to the array/hash
// reset the array/hash back to session variable
//
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./request.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-left: 300px">
            <form id="dataForm" method="POST">
                Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value=''"/>
                <input type="text" id="mi" name="mi" value="Middle Initial"     onfocus="this.value=''"/>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Last Name" onfocus="this.value=''"/><br />
                Phone: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="Phone number" onfocus="this.value=''"/> 
                <span style="margin-left:113px;">Account:</span> <input type="text" id="account" name="account" value="Account number" onfocus="this.value=''"/> <br />
                <input style="margin-left:230px" type="submit" name="submit"/>
                <input type="reset" name="clear"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

the next file is the javascript file, which handles all actions on the form.
The getCustomerInformation.php shall include all Session variables, which can be loaded using the ajax calls.

file: *request.js*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#phone').blur(function(){
        console.log('on blur was called');

        $.ajax({
            url: './getCustomerInformation.php?code=0&phone=' + this.value,            
            success: function(response, status, jqXhr) {
                var info = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#fname').val(info.fname);
                $('#mi').val(info.mi);
                $('#lname').val(info.lname);
                $('#account').val(info.account);
                console.log("successful response");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
               alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
            }
        })
    });

    $('#dataForm').submit(function(){
        console.log('form submitted');
        var phone = $('#phone').value;
        var fname = $('#fname').value;
        var mi = $('#mi').value;
        var lname = $('#lname').value;
        var account = $('#account').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: './getCustomerInformation.php?code=1&phone=' + phone +'&fname='+fname+'&mi='+mi + '&lname='+ lname +'&account='+account,
            success: function(response, status, jqXhr) {
                console.log("successful SUBMIT response");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
               alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
            },
        })
    });
})
```

file: *getCustomerInformation.php*:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['1234567'] = '{"lname": "Berg", "mi": "M", "fname": "Thomas", "account": "1234"}';
  $_SESSION['1122334'] = '{"lname": "Jordan", "mi": "C", "fname": "Jacky", "account": "4321"}';

  $phone = $_GET['phone'];
  $fname = $_GET['fname'];
  $lname = $_GET['lname'];
  $mi = $_GET['mi'];
  $acc = $_GET['account'];

  if($_GET['code'] == 0){
    if(array_key_exists('phone', $_GET) &&  array_key_exists($phone, $_SESSION)){
        print $_SESSION[$phone];
      }
  } else {
    if (array_key_exists('fname', $_GET) && array_key_exists('lname', $_GET) && array_key_exists('account', $_GET)){
      $_SESSION[$phone] = '{"lname": "' + $lname+ '", "mi": "'+ $mi + '", "fname": "'+$fname+'", "account": "'+$acc+'"}';
    } else {
      // Data are not complete - not possible to add them to the Session.
    }
  }
?>
```

My ideas:

1. I tried to use POST variables instead of GET, but then I wasn't even able to access them in *getCustomerInformation.php*. I included *type: "POST"* in the ajax methods, but it didn't help.
2. I thought there might be something wrong with the *session_start()* call, but I added it to both php files, still no change.
3. First I wanted to use an array as a Session variable and I used it as a hash in order to only need one $_SESSION['hash'] variable which holds all stored values, like:

   `$cust = array("1234567" => '{"lname": "Berg", "mi": "M", "fname": "Thomas", "account": "1234"}', "1122334" => '{"lname": "Jordan", "mi": "C", "fname": "Jacky", "account": "4321"}'  );
   $_SESSION['hash'] = $cust;`

Everytime, users enter new data I loaded the array from *$_SESSION['hash']* and save it back after writing ==> didn't work as well.

Does anyone have an idea, how I can change the code in order to be able to save the data in the backend (*getCustomerInformation.php*) using $_SESSION variable/s (better with the array-hash)?

Sorry for the large amount of code, I hope it's readable. But I thought, it might be better to include all code

for better understanding.

Comment: It is necessary to store the information in session variable?

Comment: You can clarify what is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: you say "didn't work as well" but what's mean?

Comment: If I submit some customer data I want to be able to access them in the same session by entering the related phone number (onblur) to the code..So Example:

_Jack M Daniels, Phone: 1234567, Acc: 1234_

is in the system and if I enter the phone number 1234567 to the form, the other 4 fields are auto filled by the ajax request to the backend, where the data is stored in a $_SESSION variable. 
Now, if I submit new data of a customer, I want to be able to get the new data by entering the phone number to the form automatically filled. Does this help?

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but the question is what is wrong?

Comment: the code is not working.. how do I have to _change_ it in order to get it to work :-)

sorry i didn't make that clear.

-- thank you so much for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you asked " how do I have to change it in order to get it to work". Well i made a copy (not copy & paste) of your script for test it, and split it for better understand, the first thing you must do is split the logic when are storing customer and retrieving customer info, second you must validate if your phone number exist in the request (it's the key)

One important thing is to separate the view, another is to use namespaces for well control and group values, and last but not least is to initialize values

if you front controller is the index.php you must initialize your store here

### `index.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['customers'])) {
    $_SESSION['customers'] = array(
        '1234567' => '{"lname": "Berg", "mi": "M", "fname": "Thomas", "account": "1234"}',
        '1122334' => '{"lname": "Jordan", "mi": "C", "fname": "Jacky", "account": "4321"}',
    );
}

require __DIR__ . '/index_template.php';
```

### `index_template.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 300px">
    <form id="dataForm" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User info</legend>
            <label for="fname">First name</label>
            <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"/>

            <label for="mi">Middle inicial</label>
            <input id="mi" type="text" name="mi" placeholder="Middle Initial"/>

            <label for="lname">Last name</label>
            <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Middle Initial"/>

            <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
            <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="000000"/>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account info</legend>

            <label for="account">Account</label>
            <input id="account" type="text" name="account"/>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        <input type="reset" name="clear"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as I said before, helps a lot split logics

### `postCustomerInformation.php`

```
session_start();

// example: converts $_POST['phone'] into $post_phone if exists
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'post');

// Validates that all required information was sent
if (isset($post_lname) && isset($post_fname) && isset($post_phone) && isset($post_account)) {
    $customer = array(
        'fname' => $post_fname,
        'lname' => $post_lname,
        'account' => $post_account,
        'mi' => isset($post_mi) ? $post_mi : '' // optional
    );

    $_SESSION['customers'][$post_phone] = json_encode($customer);
    // returns a valid json format header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Response");
} else {
    // returns error
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
}
```

### `getCustomerInformation.php`

```
session_start();

// example: converts $_GET['phone'] into $get_phone if exists
extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'get');

if (isset($get_phone) && isset($_SESSION['customers'][$get_phone])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $_SESSION['customers'][$get_phone];
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo '{}';
}
```

### `scripts.js`

```
;(function () {
    "use strict";

    function getCustomerInformation() {
        var phone = jQuery(this).val();

        if (!phone) {
            return;
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'getCustomerInformation.php',
            data: {
                phone: phone
            },
            success: function getCustomerInformation_success(data) {
                // for each returned value is assigned to the field
                for (var i in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        $('#' + i).val(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function postCustomerInformation(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = jQuery(this);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'postCustomerInformation.php',
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            success: function postCustomerInformation_success() {
                alert("OK");
            },
            error: function postCustomerInformation_error() {
                alert("Error");
            }
        })
    }

    // set behaviors when document is ready
    jQuery(document).ready(function document_ready() {
        jQuery('#phone').blur(getCustomerInformation);
        jQuery('#dataForm').submit(postCustomerInformation);
    });
})();
```

all code posted here was tested you can copy & paste directly but it is important to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for your verbose description and your time to write this answer.. it really helped me to understand how it's better to separate the logic of getting and storing the customer information.

But isn't there missing a _session_start()_ in the postCustomerInformation file, which handles the storing of new data, because if its missing, the data won't be saved?

I swichted the index.php and index_template.php, because the html data must be written in the index.php, because otherwise the form won't be displayed on the screen.

Comment: yes you'are right i forget `session_start()` in the postCustomerInformation.php file