# Can't get AJAX calls or session to function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have an extremely similar service like the one in this thread:

[Php: Form auto-fill using $_SESSION variables with multiple php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823890/php-form-auto-fill-using-session-variables-with-multiple-php-files#new-answer?newreg=bebd8429815b4283a418175802771492)

I would have asked there but since I don't have 50 reputation, I'll have to ask a new question.

To understand Ajax better I wanted to re-create rkmax's files and see if they would work. So I saved them as 5 separate files.

The SESSION does not seem to store any posted information. Added a `print_r($_SESSION);` to keep track of what's currently in there. Furthermore the `.blur` event to retrieve account information via the phone number doesn't work either.

Been banging my head against the wall for days with this one. It won't work when working either hosted locally via Apache/XAMPP or on an actual web server. All 5 files are in the same folder and titled exactly the same as rkmax's file titles.

I understand the logic behind each of the functions and can't seem to find a problem anywhere. I'm pretty new to coding so it could easily be something obvious like file structure or my own computer's settings?

Read a bunch of other StackOverflow threads with similar problems, but none of them seemed whatsoever applicable.

Thanks for your time.

Here's everything copied from rkmax's code:

## index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['customers'])) {
    $_SESSION['customers'] = array(
        '1234567' => '{"lname": "Berg", "mi": "M", "fname": "Thomas", "account": "1234"}',
        '1122334' => '{"lname": "Jordan", "mi": "C", "fname": "Jacky", "account": "4321"}',
    );
}

require __DIR__ . '/index_template.php';
```

## index_template.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 300px">
    <form id="dataForm" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User info</legend>
            <label for="fname">First name</label>
            <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"/>

            <label for="mi">Middle inicial</label>
            <input id="mi" type="text" name="mi" placeholder="Middle Initial"/>

            <label for="lname">Last name</label>
            <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Middle Initial"/>

            <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
            <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="000000"/>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account info</legend>

            <label for="account">Account</label>
            <input id="account" type="text" name="account"/>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        <input type="reset" name="clear"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## postCustomerInformation.php

```
session_start();

// example: converts $_POST['phone'] into $post_phone if exists
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'post');

// Validates that all required information was sent
if (isset($post_lname) && isset($post_fname) && isset($post_phone) && isset($post_account)) {
    $customer = array(
        'fname' => $post_fname,
        'lname' => $post_lname,
        'account' => $post_account,
        'mi' => isset($post_mi) ? $post_mi : '' // optional
    );

    $_SESSION['customers'][$post_phone] = json_encode($customer);
    // returns a valid json format header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Response");
} else {
    // returns error
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
}
```

## getCustomerInformation.php

```
session_start();

// example: converts $_GET['phone'] into $get_phone if exists
extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'get');

if (isset($get_phone) && isset($_SESSION['customers'][$get_phone])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $_SESSION['customers'][$get_phone];
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo '{}';
}
```

## scripts.js

```
;(function () {
    "use strict";

    function getCustomerInformation() {
        var phone = jQuery(this).val();

        if (!phone) {
            return;
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'getCustomerInformation.php',
            data: {
                phone: phone
            },
            success: function getCustomerInformation_success(data) {
                // for each returned value is assigned to the field
                for (var i in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        $('#' + i).val(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function postCustomerInformation(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = jQuery(this);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'postCustomerInformation.php',
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            success: function postCustomerInformation_success() {
                alert("OK");
            },
            error: function postCustomerInformation_error() {
                alert("Error");
            }
        })
    }

    // set behaviors when document is ready
    jQuery(document).ready(function document_ready() {
        jQuery('#phone').blur(getCustomerInformation);
        jQuery('#dataForm').submit(postCustomerInformation);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Would be much easier for everyone here if you included at least one Ajax script, the matching php script, and the HTML mark-up for it in your post.

Comment: Sure no problem. I think that should be everything.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No none, I can't get any errors to appear. Has anyone tried this code and it worked for them?

Comment: I am constructing one to test. This one you have seems overly complex for what it's trying to do (as I understand it anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I agree it does seem overly complex.

So I figured out SESSION is working after adding this little code to the index. The views is increment properly.

if ( isset ( $_SESSION['views'] ) ) {
 $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views'] + 1;
}
else {
 $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
}

Going to start looking into the jQuery next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started from scratch working on my answer pretty much nonstop, but gotta go to work soon, here's what I've got so far; I'm currently stuck on successfully sending the SESSION data back to the javascript and decoding it and displaying it successfully. Once I have that working I think sending those to the appropriate forms as well as the POST will be trivial. If anyone has any suggestions to speed me through this last part I would appreciate it.

Edit: Edited with the final solution.

## index2.php

```
    <?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['customers'])) {
    $_SESSION['customers'] = array(
        '1111111' => '{"phone": "1111111", "fname": "Za", "lname": "Zo", "mi": "Z", "account": "1234"}',
        '2222222' => '{"phone": "2222222", "fname": "La", "lname": "Li", "mi": "L", "account": "4321"}',
    );
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title> Assignment5 </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" type="text" id="phone" maxlength="7" autofocus>
        <input placeholder="First Name" name="fname" type="text" id="fname">
        <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" type="text" id="lname">
        <input placeholder="Middle Initial" name="mi" type="text" id="mi">
        <input placeholder="Account Number" name="account" type="text" id="account" maxlength="4">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## scripts.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#phone").blur(function(){

        var session;
        var currentPhone = $("#phone").val();

        $.get("getPhone.php", {phone: currentPhone}, function(data) {

            for (var i in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    $('#' + i).val(data[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("form").submit(function(){

        var form = jQuery(this);

        $.post("postPhone.php", form.serializeArray(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

## getPhone.php

```
 <?php

    session_start();

    $nowPhone = $_GET["phone"];

    if (array_key_exists($nowPhone, $_SESSION['customers'])) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $_SESSION['customers'][$nowPhone];
    } else {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo '{}';
    }

?>
```

## postPhone.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST["phone"]) && isset($_POST["fname"]) && isset($_POST["lname"]) && isset($_POST["mi"]) && isset($_POST["account"])) {

        echo ("Submitted");

        $customer = array(
            'phone' => $_POST["phone"],
            'fname' => $_POST["fname"],
            'lname' => $_POST["lname"],
            'mi' => $_POST["mi"],
            'account' => $_POST["account"],
        );

        $_SESSION['customers'][$_POST["phone"]] = json_encode($customer);
    }
    else
        echo ("All Information is Required");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and do something a bit scaled down, see if this is what you are trying to do. You only need 3 pages, the original form page, the php page, and the js file:

**/ajax/dispatch.php**

```
/*
**  @param $phone [string] Gets key from session
*/
function getCustomerByPhone($phone)
    {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['customers'][$phone])) {
            // I am decoding, but if you have the ability to set,
            // create an array like below with success and data
            $values =   json_decode($_SESSION['customers'][$phone]);
            die(json_encode(array("success"=>true,"data"=>$values)));
        }
    }

function makeError()
    {
        // Send back error
        die(json_encode(array("success"=>false,"data"=>false)));
    }
/*
** @param $array [string] This will be a query string generated from the
**                        jQuery serialize, so it's to be turned to array
*/    
function updateSession($array)
    {
        // This should come back as a string, so you will need to parse it
        $data   =   false;
        parse_str(htmlspecialchars_decode($array),$data);
        // Update the session
        $_SESSION['customers'][$data['phone']]  =   json_encode($data);
        die(json_encode(array("success"=>true,"data"=>$data)));
    }

if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    // If already exists, return to ajax the data
    getCustomerByPhone($_POST['phone']);
}
elseif(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    updateSession($_POST['data']);
}

// If not exists, return false
makeError();
```

**/scripts.js**

```
// I try not to duplicate things as much as possible
// so I would consider making an object to reuse
var AjaxEngine  =   function($)
    {
        this.ajax   =   function(url,data,func,method)
            {
                method  =   (typeof method === "undefined")? 'post' : 'get';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    type: method,
                    success: function(response) {
                        func(response);
                    }
                });
            };
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create instance
    var Ajax        =   new AjaxEngine($);
    var dispatcher  =   '/ajax/dispatch.php';
    // On submit of form
    $(this).on('submit','#dataForm',function(e) {
        // Get the form
        var thisForm    =   $(this);
        // Stop form from firing
        e.preventDefault();
        // Run ajax to dispatch
        Ajax.ajax(dispatcher,
            // Serialize form
            $('#dataForm').serialize(),
            // Create an anonymous function to handle return
            function(response) {
                // Parse
                var resp    =   JSON.parse(response);
                // See if data exists
                if(typeof resp.data === "undefined") {
                    console.log(resp.data);
                    return false;
                }
                // If there is a hit in session
                else if(resp.success == true) {
                    // Loop through it and fill empty inputs in form
                    $.each(resp.data, function(k,v){
                        var input   =   $("input[name="+k+"]");
                        if(input.length > 0) {
                            if(input.val() == '') {
                                input.val(v);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                // Run the session update
                Ajax.ajax(dispatcher,
                    // This time send an action
                    // (just to differentiate from check function)
                    {
                        "action":"update",
                        "data":thisForm.serialize()
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        // Check your console.
                        console.log(response);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your hard work! Sadly it still doesn't seem to work for me. I'm now convinced it's a problem on my end. Tested this code and SESSION still increments. But the blur call on the phone number doesn't work and neither does the post to session. Is there something I have to install for jQuery, AJAX, etc to work? Also I have uploaded an image of my file structure to make sure that isn't the problem, and in the ajax folder I have dispatch.php. (http://postimg.org/image/dafey6q9t/)

Comment: As far as what I'm trying to do, there are 2 main things I need this program to do:

1. When you input a phone number, the user information is retrieved via AJAX and populates the other fields with the user's information.
2. When you submit a new user, their data is added to the SESSION.

Comment: That's what mine does, unless you have tried it and it's not doing that for some reason.

Comment: Yeah I tried both rkmax code and your code, on both my laptop and desktop, via XAMPP and also uploaded it to a server that I know can run it. I enter "1234567" into the Phone number field every time, and click or tab out and it has no effect. The same with trying to post a new user, the contents of SESSION remain unchanged. Do you have any idea what could be causing the problem? Chrome extensions across both computers like Ghostery or ABP? Don't be afraid to mention even the most basics of basics.

Comment: Okay so this one works much better! Adding a new account to the session works perfectly, and the user information is populated when you put the phone number in and submit or press enter. This one is almost exactly what I need, except the fields should populate onblur of the phone number field instead of on submit. Then just the question remains of why it works on your tester and not for me in any other fashion. Also, after I closed the browser and re-opened the tester.php, the dummy account I made (2222222) was still there.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this matters at all, in your session output the JSON format for each of the users is a little different:

`(
    [1234567] => {"fname":"Thomas","mi":"M","lname":"Berg","phone":"1234567","account":"1234"}
    [1122334] => {"lname": "Jordan", "mi": "C", "fname": "Jacky", "account": "4321"}
    [2222222] => {"fname":"Ja","mi":"Ja","lname":"Ja","phone":"2222222","account":"2222"}
)`